# Why do these array elements become null when called in another class?

Tags: java

I instantiated my Message objects and put them in this array of messages (inbox). This was done in the Identify class. However, when I try to get those Message objects in my Filter class, the objects themselves become null and I get nothing out of it. Why?

Here's the method used to Identify emails:

```
public void identifyEmail(String input1)
    throws IOException, NumberFormatException,
ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, EmptyArrayException
{
inFile = new File(input1);
in = new Scanner(inFile);
int MESSAGE_AMOUNT = countMessage(input1);

    for(int i = 0;i<MESSAGE_AMOUNT;i++){
            noMoreMail = true;
            emailAddress = find(input1,"From:");
            if(noMoreMail){
                break;
            }
            MIN = extractInt(find(input1,"MIN:"));
            message = getMessage(input1);
            target++;

            ib.addMessage(MIN, emailAddress, message);
    }
}
```

I have an Inbox class to hold the array of Message objects:

```
public class Inbox {

public Message[] inbox;
public int messageCount;

public Inbox(){
    inbox = new Message[100];
    messageCount = 0;
}
```

Here's where the problem lies. When it cycle through the emails in the Filter class, it just goes through null Messages.

```
for(int i=0; i<ib.messageCount; i++){
        Message email = ib.inbox[i];
        System.out.println(email.getMIN());

        test1 = checkBlackList(email);
        if(!test1){test2 = checkKeyword(email);}
        // if spam mail is not on black list but still is spam

        if(test1){updateKeywords(email);}
        if(test2){addToBlackList(email);}
        if(test1 || test2){
            minToAdd = addToMINList(email);
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

addMessage method

```
public void addMessage(int MIN, String emailAddress, String message){
    if(messageCount < 100){
    Message m = new Message(MIN, emailAddress, message);
    inbox[messageCount] = m;
    messageCount++;
    } else {
    increaseSize();
    Message m = new Message(MIN, emailAddress, message);
    inbox[messageCount] = m;
    messageCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more code, but I'd guess you have two different inbox objects, your first class is populating one, and your second class is reading a blank one, instead of referencing the same object.

Comment: `inbox = new Message[100];` creates an array of 100 `null`s. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Yeah, although I only wanted to create one inbox array.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia how would I properly reference that inbox object then? When I take out that explicit constructor in the Inbox class, the problem still persists. I thought i knew how to reference objects but this is just confusing me.

Comment: I fixed it. I first used the ArrayList instead of Array to hold the messages. Then I made it static, so references should go to that one arraylist. I don't know if this is a long-term solution, but it seems to work for me so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not directly populate the members of an array, then that array is just a load of `null` values, or default values for primitive types.

**Example**

```
String[] strs = new String[10];
// Strs = {null, null .... null}

Object[] objs = new Object[10];
objs[0] = new Object();

// objs = {new Object(), null, null ... null}
```

So you see, simply by *declaring* the array, you do not *define* it's elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use ArrayList of Message objects instead of just using Array because it will give you a wide variety of features.

Looking at your code, I suspect the issue might be in the addMessage() method.

```
ib is the object of Inbox class. When you are calling the method addMessage, are you 
updating messages in the inbox array of the 'this'(i.e. the ib ) object? or you are
instantiating another Inbox object and adding the Messages there?

Could you furnish the addMessage() code up here...?
```

This is not an answer and should be treated as a comment. Please don't accept it as an answer.
I do not have sufficient privileges to post a comment.

Please don't negate it as well.

Comment: new to this. The code won't load up so I put it on the main post.

Comment: I saw. Your addMessage method looks good.

Whatever Chris says is correct, you have to initialize the size of the array. 

It is a dynamic implementation of array and will help you during all basic functions applicable to your code.

To do it correctly, I would suggest use java.util.ArrayList.